# FreeMarker ansi colors for console output

Tags: freemarker

I'm using a Freemarker template the generate output for a cli tool.

Is it possible to add ANSI colors like `\u001B[34m` to the template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the question is about the `\u001B` (`ESC`). You can print that either by literarily including it in the template, or with `${'\x1B'}`. Of course manually inserting escape sequences is still no much fun, so you might write some macros for it, for example:

```
<#macro fg color>${'\x1B'}[${30 + color}m</#macro>

<@fg 4 />This is blue. <@fg 2 />This is green.
```